# ¿como permitir el uso de styles o css en libreria HTML Purifier Laravel 10?

Tags: html, laravel

Entonces llevo un rato probando HTML purifier para limpiar el html que el usuario puede guardar en la base de datos en mi crud hecho con laravel. Tengo esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Closure;
use HTMLPurifier;
use HTMLPurifier_Config;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;

class HtmlPurified implements ValidationRule
{
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        // Agrega los estilos permitidos en línea al conjunto de elementos permitidos
        $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'strong,p,b,a[href],i,u,h1,h2,h3,h4,span[style]');
        // Agrega los estilos específicos permitidos en línea
        $config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'color');

        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

        $cleanValue = $purifier->purify($value);

        if ($cleanValue !== $value) {
            $fail("El campo :attribute contiene caracteres no permitidos.");
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'El campo :attribute contiene caracteres no permitidos.';
    }
}
```

Pero no permite el ingreso de estilos css llevo un buen rato buscando alguna solucion pero en todas sigo igual.
Por ejemplo en mi campo para agregar contenido tengo algo asi
`<span style="color: rgb(224, 62, 45);" data-mce-style="color: rgb(224, 62, 45);"> texto</span>` pero html purifier no me permite guardar esto.
Como punto extra estoy usando tiny mce para ingresar la informacion no se que me falta o donde estoy mal.